# Disable language saving at registration?

Tags: registration

I use joomla 3.3, the site has 2 languages, English and French, can i disable language insert during registration? If someone create a new account, then his frontend language don't should be inserted, i want if someone after reg. do a login in other language, then he should stay also in actuall language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to disable front-end Language option:**

In the backend, Click to **Users** menu item (com_users). 
When in Users manager, click the **Options** button (top right).
In the Configuration of the users component, around the middle there is the option to **Hide** the **Front-End Language**.

However, from your question I understand that while you don't want the user to have to choose his front-end language during registration, you would like the system understands that his language is the same as the one he has chosen during browsing before login.

But here comes a sort of conflict. That's because when a user have not set a language preference, then he is assigned with the default front-end site language. 
The fact that after login you see the user switching back to another language is because the system reads his account setting of the default site language and it switches him to that language.

If you try the login from the default front-end language, with the same user, then his language view won't be switched after login.

In theory, it should be possible to overcome this, with the following way - although I haven't try it at all.

The theory: 
You could override the template of the registration form or module and have the language preference field enabled but hidden. There you could check for the page language which will set the form's language preference accordingly and pass it to the database in the background during the user's registration.

If I have some time, I may experiment with the above and come back with more details.

Ah and a question: Why you don't want the Language Setting during registration? Since this is multilingual website, it really makes sense.